# Using LINQ, where one object property has a value of x, how do I return the value in a different property

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object, which I'm trying to query against instantiations of using LINQ. Where one property of an object has a given value, I need to return the value of another property

My constructor is as below:

```
public Job(string organisationType, string contractingOrganisationType, int levelNumber, string 
jobName, int jobNumberOnLevel, string jobExecutor, int stepCount, int customInputCount, int 
customOutputCount)
{
OrganisationType = organisationType;
ContractingOrganisationType = contractingOrganisationType;
LevelNumber = levelNumber;
JobName = jobName;
JobNumberOnLevel = jobNumberOnLevel;
JobExecutor = jobExecutor;
StepCount = stepCount;
CustomInputCount = customInputCount;
CustomOutputCount = customOutputCount;
}
```

A couple of mock instances look as below:

```
List<Job> JobList = new List<Job>();
JobList.Add(new Job("Owner" , null , 0, "ProjectBriefCreation" , 1, "ProjectOwner" , 5, 2, 2));
JobList.Add(new Job("GeneralContractor" , "Owner" , 1, "ProjectManagement" , 1, "ContractsManager" , 
7, 2, 2));
JobList.Add(new Job("DesignContractor" , "Owner" , 1, "DesignManagement" , 2, 
"DesignContractsManager", 7, 2, 2));
JobList.Add(new Job("ArchitecturalPractice" , "DesignContractor" , 2, "BuildingDesign" , 1, 
"LeadArchitect" , 7, 2, 2));
JobList.Add(new Job("StructuralEngineeringPractice", "DesignContractor" , 2, "StructuralDesign" , 2, 
"StructuralEngineer" , 7, 2, 2));
JobList.Add(new Job("Carpentry" , "GeneralContractor", 2, "Drywalling" , 3, "Carpenter" , 5, 2, 2));
JobList.Add(new Job("PlasteringAndPainting" , "GeneralContractor", 2, "Plastering" , 4, "Plasterer" , 
6, 2, 2));
JobList.Add(new Job("PlasteringAndPainting" , "GeneralContractor", 2, "Painting" , 5, "Painter" , 8, 
2, 2));
```

My query so far looks like this (though not working obviously):

```
int jobStepNodeCountForJob = JobList.Where(j => j.LevelNumber == 1).Where(j => j.JobNumberOnLevel == 
2).Select(;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which property do you want to get? You should specify that in the `select`

Comment: Where returns an _IEnumerable<Job>_ here. If your query returns a single object or null then you should use FirstOrDefault, then after checking for null you can grab the property you want from the Job returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return eg the `StepCount` for all Job whose LevelNumber is 1 and JobNumberOnLevel is 2:

```
IEnumerable<int> jobStepCounts = JobList
  .Where(j => j.LevelNumber == 1 && j => j.JobNumberOnLevel == 2)
  .Select(j => j.StepCount);
```

BEcause there is more than one potential match, you'll get a collection of items out; you can't store multiple of those in an int

If you want multiple properties, you could project a new collection of anonymous types, for example:

```
var jobStepCountAndJobNames = JobList
  .Where(j => j.LevelNumber == 1 && j => j.JobNumberOnLevel == 2)
  .Select(j => new { j.StepCount, j.JobName });
```

It's easier to var it than try and declare an exact type for these anonymous things.

---

To return the first job StepCount that matches the criteria:

```
int jobStepCount = JobList
  .FirstOrDefault(j => j.LevelNumber == 1 && j => j.JobNumberOnLevel == 2).StepCount;
```

Note that this can crash if there is no matching job; it will return a null that then crashes upon access with a null reference exception. You can do something like:

```
int? jobStepCount = JobList
  .FirstOrDefault(j => j.LevelNumber == 1 && j => j.JobNumberOnLevel == 2)?.StepCount;
```

The `?.` before stepcount will not try to access stepcount on the null that is returned if no job matches. It will just immediately return the null and the nullable `int?` will have no value

---

If you don't want a single result, but instead an average, sum, or other aggregation of all the stepcounts, look at something like:

```
int jobStepCountAverage = JobList
  .Where(j => j.LevelNumber == 1 && j => j.JobNumberOnLevel == 2)
  .Average(j => j.StepCount);
```

Comment: Great, thanks Caius. This first option will work for me, as my setup should only allow for one 'StepCount' value against the combination of properties in the where.

Comment: Always program defensively though ;) - you might be certain that you'll never have more than one Job with level 1 and onlevel 2.. and then the new employee starts and puts all sorts of crazy data in.. If there's a chance that one day there will be multiples and you at least want to cause a crash with a reasonable error message rather than potentially process based on the wrong thing, you can use `Single` / `SingleOrDefault` rather than `First` Single throws an exception if multiple items match

Comment: You are right, of course and point taken. Before I go live, I'm going to attach a GUID in there for every upload. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I dunno what property you want to trap, here i suppose you want the enumerate List of JobName:

```
var jobStepNodeCountForJob = JobList.Where(j => j.LevelNumber == 1 && j.JobNumberOnLevel ==2).Select(j => j.JobName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to both select the chosen property and since it can be many matching nodes choose how to reduce them to a single number. I think this is what you want

```
int jobStepNodeCountForJob = JobList
    .Where(j => j.LevelNumber == 1 && j.JobNumberOnLevel == 2)
    .Select(j => j.StepCount)
    .Sum();
```

I'd download LINQpad or use a similar tool to get a feeling for linq.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, I'm going to check out that LINQpad. LINQ is certainly proving tricky to get my head around.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Example()
{
    // Two examples:
    // 1. You want the FIRST value of some int property from your object (CustomInputCount int this example)
    // Output: '2' 
    // Please note: When using FirstOrDefault() if no result is coming from the condition you will get a null value 
    int jobStepNodeCountForJob = JobList.Where(j => j.LevelNumber == 1 && j.JobNumberOnLevel == 2)
    .Select(x => x.CustomInputCount).FirstOrDefault();

    // 2. You want the all values of some int property from your object (CustomInputCount int this example) as a list
    // Output (List<int>) -> {2,2,2,2,2,2}        
    List<int> jobStepNodeCountForJob_List = JobList.Where(j => j.LevelNumber == 1 && j.JobNumberOnLevel == 2)
    .Select(x => x.CustomInputCount).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var jobExecutor= JobList.FirstOrDefault(j => j.LevelNumber == 1 && j.JobNumberOnLevel ==2)?.JobExecutor;
```

It will find firs Job in the list that fits the condition in brackets and assign it's `JobExecutor` field to `jobExecutor` variable or null if such job not found.